# Right click on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to write a Minesweeper clone in Java for fun.  I have a grid of JButtons whose labels I will change to represent the danger count, flags, etc.

My problem is, I don't know how to get a right click on a JButton to depress the button.  I've done the following:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        boolean mine = field.isMine(x, y);
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            button.setText("F");
        }
        else {
            if (mine) {
                button.setText("X");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working at all; the "F" is never shown, only the "X" part.  But more importantly, this does nothing for depressing the button.

EDIT: Macs have popup trigger happen on mousePress, not mouseClick.

EDIT: Here's the solution I worked out based off of accepted answer:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            boolean pressed;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                button.getModel().setArmed(true);
                button.getModel().setPressed(true);
                pressed = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //if(isRightButtonPressed) {underlyingButton.getModel().setPressed(true));
                button.getModel().setArmed(false);
                button.getModel().setPressed(false);

                if (pressed) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        button.setText("F");
                    }
                    else {
                        button.setText("X");
                    }
                }
                pressed = false;

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed = true;
            }                    
        });
        add(button);
```

[Minesweeper clone http://grab.by/1y9z](http://grab.by/1y9z)

Comment: And yes I realize the final board should not have all those numbers shown.  I'm just developing.

Comment: What do you need this `popupTrigger` stuff for? Just check for events mousePressed and check the event's modifiers for BUTTON1_MASK or BUTTON2_MASK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Button can't be pressed by right click. Add such a lines to you mouse listener

mousePressed:

```
if(isRightButtonPressed) {underlyingButton.getModel().setPressed(true));
```

mouseReleased:

```
if(needReset) {underlyingButton.getModel().setPressed(false));
```

or do there whatever want.

Comment: I will try this tonight; looks most promising.

Comment: In order for the visual cues to work correctly, need to call setArmed() before setPressed()

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use `isPopupTrigger` but directly check for the right button:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    boolean mine = field.isMine(x, y);
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
      button.setText("F");
    }
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addition: the simplest way to check for the right button is `SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton`

Comment: This does not work for ctrl+click on mac which usually triggers right click.

Answer (score 1):

[MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) has some properties

```
static int BUTTON1
static int BUTTON2
static int BUTTON3
```

among others. Check those when your event fires.

EDIT

> public int getButton()

```
Returns which, if any, of the mouse buttons has changed state.
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get which button was pressed, but that's no longer my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that checking for "mousePressed" solved your issue. And the Javadoc of [isPopupTrigger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger()) would explain the need for this:

**public boolean isPopupTrigger()**
...
*Note: Popup menus are triggered differently on different systems. Therefore, isPopupTrigger should be checked in both mousePressed and mouseReleased for proper cross-platform functionality.*

Also see the section on *The Mouse Listener API* in the Java [Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The button being visibly depressed on right click isn't part of the "normal" behavior of buttons. You may be able to fake it using `JToggleButton`s, or simply changing the button's background color and maybe border while the right mouse button is being held down.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the event is properly being triggered (debug FTW!) and that the button.setText("F") is happening, then perhaps you simply need to repaint.

Repaint the button.
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(java.awt.Rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me fine on Mac:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTest extends JFrame {

    JButton button;

    public ButtonTest() {
        button = new JButton("W");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == 3) { // if right click
                    button.setText("F");
                    button.getModel().setPressed(false);
                    // button.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    button.setText("X");
                    button.getModel().setPressed(true);
                    // button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(button);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonTest();
    }

}
```

You might as well check for e.getButton() == 2 but I don't know when this one is triggered on Macs.