# Flagging Buttons for Minesweeper GUI Game

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, minesweeper

I have worked for hours on this code and finally gotten ver close to completion. I will be adding a Mine Counter and a timer once I figure out how to add the ability to flag mines with right clicking. I learned that JButtons do not recognize right clicks, so I must use a MouseEvent. From there, I'm lost. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

This is what I currently have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MineSweeper implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mine Sweeper");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[20][20];//button array
    JButton[] flags = new JButton[20];
    int[][] counts = new int[20][20];
    Container grid = new Container(); //grid for buttons
    int MineNum = 50;//number of mines
    final int MINE = 10;//int value to identify a mine



    public MineSweeper() {
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(reset, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        //Grid of Buttons
        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20));
        for (int a = 0; a<buttons.length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < buttons[0].length; b++) {
                buttons[a][b] = new JButton("▒");
                buttons[a][b].addActionListener(this);
                buttons[a][b].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                            mineFlagger(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
                grid.add(buttons[a][b]);
            }
        }
        frame.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        makeRandomMines();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mineFlagger (boolean flag){
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++) {
                if(flag == true) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("F");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MineSweeper();
    }

    public void makeRandomMines() {
        //initializes list of random pairs
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
                list.add(x * 100 + y);//changed y to x
            }
        }
        //resets the counts in case reset button is pressed & picks random mines
        counts = new int[20][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < MineNum; i++) {
            int choice = (int) (Math.random() * list.size());
            counts[list.get(choice) / 100][list.get(choice) % 100] = MINE;
            list.remove(choice);
        }
        //neighbor counts(how many mines are touching this square.)
        for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
                int neighborCount = 0;
                if (counts[x][y] != MINE) {
                    if(x > 0 && y > 0 && counts[x - 1][y - 1] == MINE) { //a mine is up & left
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(y > 0 && counts[x][y - 1] == MINE) { //a mine is up
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(x < counts.length - 1 && y > 0 && counts[x + 1][y - 1] == MINE) { // a mine is left
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(x > 0 && counts[x - 1][y] == MINE) { //left
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(x < counts.length - 1 && counts[x + 1][y] == MINE) { //mine is right
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(x > 0 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x - 1][y + 1] == MINE) { //mine is down
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x][y + 1]== MINE) {//mine is up right
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if(x < counts[0].length - 1 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && counts[x + 1][y + 1]== MINE) {//mine is down left
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    counts[x][y] = neighborCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void lostGame() {
        for (int x = 0; x < buttons.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < buttons[0].length; y++) {
                if (buttons[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    if (counts[x][y] != MINE) {
                        buttons[x][y].setText(counts[x][y] + "");
                        buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        buttons[x][y].setText("✪");
                        buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose!\n" + "You clicked on a mine!", "BOOM!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void checkWin() {
        boolean winner = true;

        for (int x = 0; x < counts.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < counts[0].length; y++) {
                if (counts[x][y] != MINE && buttons[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    winner = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (winner == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You win!");
        }
    }

    public void zeroCleaner(ArrayList<Integer> toClear) {
        if (toClear.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            int x = toClear.get(0) / 100;
            int y = toClear.get(0) % 100;
            toClear.remove(0);
            if(x > 0 && y > 0 && buttons[x-1][y-1].isEnabled()) { //up and left
                buttons[x - 1][y - 1].setText(counts[x-1][y-1] + "");
                buttons[x - 1][y - 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x - 1][y - 1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x-1) * 100 + (y-1));
                }
            }
            if (y > 0 && buttons[x][y-1].isEnabled()) { // up
                buttons[x][y - 1].setText(counts[x][y-1] + "");
                buttons[x][y - 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x][y - 1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add(x * 100+(y - 1));
                }
            }
            if (x < counts.length - 1 && y > 0 && buttons[x+1][y-1].isEnabled()) { //up right
                buttons[x + 1][y - 1].setText(counts[x+1][y-1] + "");
                buttons[x + 1][y - 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x + 1][y - 1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x + 1)*100+(y - 1));
                }
            }
            if(x > 0 && y > 0 && buttons[x-1][y].isEnabled()) { //left
                buttons[x - 1][y].setText(counts[x-1][y] + "");
                buttons[x - 1][y].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x-1][y] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x-1)*100+y);
                }
            }
            if (x < counts.length - 1 && buttons[x+1][y].isEnabled()) { //right
                buttons[x + 1][y].setText(counts[x+1][y] + "");
                buttons[x + 1][y].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x + 1][y] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x + 1)*100+y);
                }
            }
            if(x > 0 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && buttons[x-1][y+1].isEnabled()) { //down and left
                buttons[x - 1][y + 1].setText(counts[x-1][y+1] + "");
                buttons[x - 1][y + 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x-1][y+1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x-1)*100+(y+1));
                }
            }
            if (y < counts[0].length - 1 && buttons[x][y+1].isEnabled()) { // down
                buttons[x][y + 1].setText(counts[x][y+1] + "");
                buttons[x][y + 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x][y + 1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add(x * 100+(y + 1));
                }
            }
            if (x < counts.length - 1 && y < counts[0].length - 1 && buttons[x+1][y+1].isEnabled()) { //down right
                buttons[x + 1][y + 1].setText(counts[x+1][y+1] + "");
                buttons[x + 1][y + 1].setEnabled(false);
                if (counts[x + 1][y + 1] == 0) {
                    toClear.add((x + 1)*100+(y + 1));
                }
            }
            zeroCleaner(toClear);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource().equals(reset)) {
         //Resets the playing field
            for (int x = 0; x < buttons.length; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < buttons[0].length; y++) {
                    buttons[x][y].setEnabled(true);
                    buttons[x][y].setText("▒");
                }
            }
            makeRandomMines();
        }
        else {
            for (int x = 0; x < buttons.length ; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < buttons[0].length; y++) {
                    if(event.getSource().equals(buttons[x][y])) {
                        if (counts[x][y]== MINE) {
                            lostGame();
                        }
                        else if(counts[x][y] == 0) {
                            buttons[x][y].setText(counts[x][y]+ "");
                            buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                            ArrayList<Integer> toClear = new ArrayList<>();
                            toClear.add(x*100+y);
                            zeroCleaner(toClear);
                            checkWin();
                        }
                        else {
                            buttons[x][y].setText(counts[x][y]+ "");
                            buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                            checkWin();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have the code that checks for which button was pressed: `e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3`

Comment: @Jhonny007 `MouseEvent.BUTTON3` is ambiguous. Button3 might vary depending on the mouse/OS etc... Also, he's asking how detecting the right click can be tied to the button it is hovering over. Because as he says, buttons can't directly detect right-clicks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006188/right-click-on-jbutton'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
for (int a = 0; a<buttons.length; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < buttons[0].length; b++) {
        buttons[a][b] = new JButton("▒");
        buttons[a][b].addActionListener(this);
        final int finalB = b;
        final int finalA = a;
        buttons[a][b].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    mineFlagger(true, finalA, finalB);
                }
            }
        });
        grid.add(buttons[a][b]);
    }
}


public void mineFlagger (boolean flag, int x, int y){
    buttons[x][y].setText("F");
}
```

---

**Edit:** for toggling the flag (lazy implementation)

```
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
    mineFlagger(finalA, finalB);
}

public void mineFlagger(int x, int y) {
    if(buttons[x][y].getText().equals("F")) {
        buttons[x][y].setText("▒");
    } else if (buttons[x][y].getText().equals("▒")){
        buttons[x][y].setText("F");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! How could I make it so when right clicked again it reverts back to normal?

Comment: I added a solution for that problem as well though that is not a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you import 'javax.swing.SwingUtilities' you could use utilities methods:

```
SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent)
```

Then when a right mouse button is pressed, get the location of the mouse, find the button at that location, and then use that event to change the picture on that particular button to a picture of a flag.

You could use:

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

To obtain the location of the mouse relative to the screen.